# is it possible to set the splitting strategy for GridSearchCv?

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I'm optimizing model's hyperparameters by GridSearchCv. And because the data I'm working with is very imbalanced, I need to "choose" the manner that the algortihm splits the train/test sets in order to ensure that the underrepresented points are in both sets.

By reading scikit-learn's documentation, I have the idea that it's possible to set the splitting strategy for GridSearch but I'm not sure how or if this is the case.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pass in the `GridSearchCV` as `cv` a [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) object.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv = skf)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you are training a classification model with GridSearchCV, the default method for splitting the dataset is StratifiedKFold, that takes care of balancing the dataset according to the target variable.

If your dataset is imbalanced for some other reason (not the target variable), you can choose another criteria to perform the split. Carefully read the documentation of GridSearchCV, and select an appropriate [CV splitter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-CV-splitter).

In the scikit-learn documentation of [model selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection), there are many Splitter Classes that you could use. Or you can define your own splitter class according to your criteria, but it would be more difficult.